# Math.getExponent function

Tags: java, android, exponent, math-functions

I am trying to use the below code for one of my apps, and it requires the use of the exponential function:

```
YPO = ((590 * (Math.getExponent((n2 / n1) * 258.2))) / 1.12) / 60;
```

Where n1 and n2 are any number between 0.1 to 0.9

The problem is I am getting YPO = 0, but when I am calculating (n2 / n1) * 258.2, I am getting a decimal number. Its exponential shouldn't be zero, but still it is giving output as zero. Can someone please let me know if I am using the above mentioned function correctly?

the relevant code of my app:

[image]

Comment: Reverify the type of your variables

Comment: Its of double type

Comment: When n1, n2 and YPO are double, i obtain non zero value. What's the value of n1 and n2 ?

Comment: Its 0.5 and 0.6 respectively, but you can take any number between 0.1 and 0.9

Comment: I get answer 70.23809523809523

Comment: I am still getting zero! Have you done any modifications? I have edited my question and added a screenshot too, can you please have a look and let me know?

Comment: I see now. You have not initialized any of your variables. By default, the compiler will assign the values 0.0d to n1 and n2 and generate an alert.

Comment: Thanks for the constant reply Mandarin! I have initialized the variables now, below is the code:                                                                                                                   
    public double n1 = 1.0d;
    public double n2 = 1.0d;
    public double n3 = 1.0d;                                                                       I am still getting output as zero, what else can I do :(

Comment: Can you please share your code and let me know how have you implemented the same?

Comment: double n1 = 0.5,n2=0.6;
        double YPO = ((590 * (Math.getExponent((n2 / n1) * 258.2))) / 1.12) / 60;

Comment: import java.lang.Math

Comment: What do you mean by "the exponential function"? I guess you probably wanted `Math.exp` instead of `Math.getExponent` (which behaves more like a logarithm of base 2).

Comment: @leMandarin I don't want to hard code the values, I am taking input from the user, that is why I haven't initialized the n1 and n2. Is there any other way of doing the same?

Comment: Display the recovery code of one of your entries please